# MongoDB - PHP - Unsupported projection option

Tags: php, mongodb

The following command works from the mongo command line:

```
db.users.aggregate([ 
    {'$match': 'eventDate':
        {$gte: ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00.0Z"), 
         $lte: ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.0Z")}
   }, 
   {'$project' : 
       {'year' : 
           { $year: '$eventDate' }
       }
   }
])
```

this should be the php equivalent:

```
$mongoConnection = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager();
$collection = 'test.users';
$query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query(
    ['eventDate' => array('$gte' => ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00.0Z, '$lte' => ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.0Z)],
    ['projection' => ['year' => [ '$year' => '$eventDate' ]]]]
);
$cursor = $mongoConnection->executeQuery( $collection, $query );
```

but I get: Unsupported projection option: year: { $year: "$eventDate" }

if I remove the 'projection' part of the Query, then it executes correctly. I have researched the error, and the only answer I could find was 'in a projection field names do not start with $'.

So I have tried all combinations of { $year: "$eventDate" } with or without $ but I still get the Unsupported projection option error.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to do "$first.eventDate"?

Comment: year => 1? That's how we do in mongoose. Just put the numbers (0 for not showing and 1 for showing)

Comment: sorry, just found the error. I should have used 'project' instead of 'projection'. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So answer your own question or delete it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want `projection` but you mean `project`.

The Projection only allows the types listed on this page in the manual:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#projection-operators